# Retrieving creation date of file (FTP)

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm using the `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` class and my code is as follows:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/folder");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string names = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

This is based off of the examples provided on MSDN but I couldn't find anything more detailed.

I'm storing all the filenames in the folder in `names` but how can I now iterate through each of those and retrieve their dates? I want to retrieve the dates so I can find the newest files. Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly sure ftp only has support for modified dates, not creation dates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory` returns a "short listing" of all the files in an FTP directory. This type of listing is only going to provide file names - not additional details on the file (like permissions or last modified date).

Use `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails` instead. This method will return a long listing of files on the FTP server. Once you've retrieved this list into the `names` variable, you can split the `names` variable into an array based on an end of line character. This will result in each array element being a file (or directory) name listing that includes the permissions, last modified date owner, etc...

At this point, you can iterate over this array, examine the last modified date for each file, and decide whether to download the file.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Works in theory but the response from the FTP server complicates things significantly.

Comment: If you can share the response you're getting from the server - maybe I can provide some futher assistance. My answer was intentionally a bit generic because the actual response from the server is going to vary from server to server.

Comment: just to clarify, this is the *modifed* date not the *created* date, which is what was asked for, right?

Answer (score 27):

This seems to work just fine
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.lastmodified(v=VS.90).aspx

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1}",serverUri,response.LastModified);
```

Comment: just to clarify, this is the *modifed* date not the *created* date, which is what was asked for, right?

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, there's no really reliable and efficient way to retrieve timestamps using features offered by .NET framework, as it does not support the FTP `MLSD` command. The `MLSD` command provides a listing of remote directory in a standardized machine-readable format. The command and the format is standardized by [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7).

Alternatives you can use, that are supported by .NET framework:

- `ListDirectoryDetails` method (the FTP `LIST` command) to retrieve details of all files in a directory and then you deal with FTP server specific format of the details (*nix format similar to the `ls` *nix command is the most common, a drawback is that the format may change over time, as for newer files "May  8 17:48" format is used and for older files "Oct 18  2009" format is used).

  DOS/Windows format: [C# class to parse WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails FTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060983/850848#39771146)
  *nix format: [Parsing FtpWebRequest ListDirectoryDetails line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013486/850848#40045894)
- `GetDateTimestamp` method (the FTP `MDTM` command) to individually retrieve timestamps for each file. An advantage is that the response is standardized by [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-3) to `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[.sss]`. A disadvantage is that you have to send a separate request for each file, what can be quite inefficient.

  ```
  const string uri = "ftp://example.com/remote/path/file.txt";
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", uri, response.LastModified);
  ```

---

Alternatively you can use a 3rd party FTP client implementation that supports the modern `MLSD` command.

For example [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) supports that.

There's even an example for your specific task: [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).
The example is for PowerShell and the SFTP, but translates to C# and the FTP easily:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Get list of files in the directory
    string remotePath = "/remote/path/";
    RemoteDirectoryInfo directoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

    // Select the most recent file
    RemoteFileInfo latest =
        directoryInfo.Files
            .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)
            .First();

    // Download the selected file
    string localPath = @"C:\local\path\";
    string sourcePath = RemotePath.EscapeFileMask(remotePath + latest.Name);
    session.GetFiles(sourcePath, localPath).Check();
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

First you will need to break apart the names using `String.Split` on the filename delimiter. Then iterate through all of the strings and navigate the directories

Comment: Command ListDirectory does not provide any details about the files, there is nothing to split.