# No year being returned using ListDirectoryDetails C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ftp

I wonder if someone can help. I am using WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails, to list directory details over a FTP connection. However i've noticed that no year is being returned, so I am getting results such as

> -rw-------    1 1003     1003        79947 Oct 02 10:27 D9694396.D239265890.DWA2540.Z

I really need the year, so that I can fully parse the date. This is a Unix based server, which I can't configure. I also don't really want to use a 3rd party library as this is just a simple directory listing. I also don't really want to use GetDateTimestamp, as we are looking at 1000's of files.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# class to parse WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails FTP response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060983/c-sharp-class-to-parse-webrequestmethods-ftp-listdirectorydetails-ftp-response)

Comment: I agree along the similar lines. However that question doesn't offer any suitable answers, apart from using a 3rd party package, which i don't want to do!

Comment: @VinceAshby-Smith, you may want to explain that in your post so other people can undersatnd...

Comment: In that question and its comments and answers it is explained that each piece of FTP server software may return the listing in a different format. You will have to configure the server to return the date. Then you can decide to either parse it yourself or by using a (free) library. If you can't configure the server, you can't get the year. You can perhaps also just call [`GetDateTimestamp` (`MDTM`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.getdatetimestamp.aspx) on each file.

Comment: @Codecaster Unix doesn't return year if the date is less than a year ago. There's nothing to configure - just improve client-side parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that Unix doesn't gives year unless the file is from the previous year and for the current year it gives time. So get around this i've used the following code:

```
if (unParsedCreateTime.Contains(":"))
{
    var x = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + unParsedCreateTime);
}
else
{
    var x = Convert.ToDateTime(unParsedCreateTime);    
}
```

Comment: Unix usually returns no year if the file is less than a year old (not "previous year" or "this year"). Note, that MacOS returns listings with no year when the file is younger than 183 days (this matters for files with future dates - they are listed differently in Unix and Mac).