# The given Path's format is not supported when accessing the files in FTP

Tags: c#

Here is my code;

```
string filedate = "ftp://72.242.29.132/TestArca/Test" +directories[i].ToString();
int j = filedate.IndexOf(":");
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(filedate);
```

I am getting problem at the third line as given path's format is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

File.GetCreationTime only works with files. You are trying to get the date of a ftp resource.
Try something like this:

[Retrieving creation date of file (FTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454281/retrieving-creation-date-of-file-ftp)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you wrote it is valid for local files. I would suggest going like  :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.lastmodified%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And modify the code like this

```
  string temp = response.StatusDescription;
      temp = temp.Substring(temp.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
      string FileCreationDateTime= temp.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + temp.Substring(4, 2) + "-" + temp.Substring(6, 2);
```

Comment: But this get the lastmodified date. The user want to get the creation date of the file.