# I want to fetch the name of the latest updated folder at particular path of FTP server

Tags: windows, ftp

Using this command I am able to get the latest updated folder in Unix

```
ls -t1 | head -1
```

But how can I get the same in FTP server from Windows?

I want to get the name of the latest updated folder at particular path of FTP server. Could any one please help?

Comment: On what platform? What ftp client do you have available?

Comment: Hi Martin, It's on linux platform(putty). Using shell programming, am able to navigate to the particular path of ftp server and fetch the files. But how can I navigate to the latest updated subfolder of particular path of ftp server and get the files. I am looking for shell command that logs into ftp directory, navigates to the path I provide in advance and fetch the latest updated directory(sub folder) in it

Comment: I mean what's your client platform. Not what is the server platform. I assume you do not run PuTTY on Linux. It's typically run on Windows to connect to Linux server.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes windows is my client platform. I run putty on windows platform to connect to ftp server

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this with Windows shell commands.

You can:

- Use `ftp.exe` to execute `ls /path c:\local\path\listing.txt` to save a directory listing to a text file.
- Exit `ftp.exe`.
- Parse the listing and find the latest files. Not an easy task for Windows shell commands.

---

It would be a way easier with a PowerShell script.

You can use [`FtpWebRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest). Though it does not have an easy way to retrieve structured directory listing either. It offers only `ListDirectoryDetails` and `GetDateTimestamp` methods.

See [Retrieving creation date of file (FTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4454281/850848).

---

Or use a 3rd-party library for the task.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can do:

```powershell
param (
    $sessionUrl = "ftp://user:mypassword@example.com/",
    $remotePath = "/path"
)

# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl)

# Connect
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Get list of files in the directory
$directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

# Select the most recent file
$latest =
    $directoryInfo.Files |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1

# Any file at all?
if ($latest -eq $Null)
{
    Write-Host "No file found"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "The latest file is $latest"
}
```

See full example [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*