# String.Split against FTP file

Tags: c#, regex, ftp, split, string-parsing

I am downloading files from an FTP server. Some of the file names have spaces in them but my RegEx doesn't recognise this.

Example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp        8613651 Apr 15  2011 Crystal Reports User Guide.pdf
```

Code:

```
string[] splitDownloadFile = Regex.Split(dFile, @"\s+");
string fMonth = splitDownloadFile[5];
string fDate = splitDownloadFile[6];
string fyear = splitDownloadFile[7];
string fName = splitDownloadFile[8];
```

Is it possible to set the string fName to be the rest of the string?

Comment: perhaps a more formal regular expression would be better.

Comment: you want to delete all spaces?

Comment: Shouldn't that be RegEx rather than ReGex?

Comment: Why don't use a client to threat this as a proper file over FTP status?

Comment: @abatishchev How would I go about doing that

Comment: How do you currently get this string?

Comment: Have you looked at [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)?

Comment: @abatishchev This is how is am getting the string  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946862/download-files-from-an-ftp-server

Comment: I've answered in that thread.

Comment: using the ListDirectory instead of the ListDirectoryDetails as you suggest doesn't give me the file details that I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to use the String.Split method instead of Regex.Split, you could use the [String.Split Method (Char[], Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) overload you can achieve the results you want.  You'd need to work out exactly what whitespace characters you need to cater for.

Something like:

```
string test = "-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp        8613651 Apr 15  2011 Crystal Reports User Guide.pdf";
string[] parts = test.Split(new[] { '\t', ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you really want to use Regex, you could do something like this to reassemble the filename:

```
string[] again = Regex.Split(test, "\\s+");
var fname = string.Join(" ", again.Skip(8).ToArray());
```

You would need a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.  The filename would, however, be only an approximation of the original one.  Multiple consecutive spaces or tab characters would have been replaced with a single space.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `string.Split()` method from the [.NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)
 and specify the maximum number of splits.

This way the last part (filename) would not be split into separate parts.

**EDIT: Code**

```
string s = "-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp        8613651 Apr 15  2011 Crystal Reports User Guide.pdf";
string[] c = {" ", "\t"};
string[] p = s.Split(c, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string name = p[8];
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Comment: @L.B: Oops... Too hasty and no testing.

Comment: Ok I justed tested it and added code that worked for the given example.

Comment: The OP's use of the \s Regex pattern allows for other whitespace characters (tab, non-breaking, etc.).  So would need to add to the array `c` all the charactes that ought to be handled.

Comment: That will include the year as part of the name. Should be 9 for the split option and `p[8]` for the name.

Comment: @JasonDown - Oh good catch - the year probably is not part of the name.

Answer (score 4):

Capturing groups make this easy.

```
var match = Regex.Match(dFile, @"\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<month>\S+)\s+(?<date>\S+)\s+(?<year>\S+)\s+(?<name>.+)");

string fName = match.Groups["name"].Value;
```

Comment: How about `Regex.Match(dFile, @"(\S+\s+){4}+(?<month>\S+)\s+(?<date>\S+)\s+(?<year>\S+)\s+(?<name>.+)");`?

Answer (score 1):

btw you may try to to glue/join all words starting n-th:

```
string fileName = String.Join("", splitDownloadFile.Skip(7)); // if file name starts from 8th segment
```

Actually that's just a workaround to improper usage of `Split()`, but for you knowledge how can you fix that.

Comment: @agent-j: You will glue them all, will you not?

Comment: This is assuming the file name will always be the same format.

Comment: @Xaisoft: This assumes that ftp file status always has file name starting 8th segment. From OP statement, it's true.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is consistent, don't split but put into and extract out of named capture groups

```
string data = "-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp        8613651 Apr 15  2011 Crystal Reports User Guide.pdf";

string pattern = @"
^                       # Beginning Anchor
(?<Permissions>[^\s]+)  # Get permissions into named capture
(?:\s+)                 # Match but don't capture space
(?<Count>\d+)
(?:\s+)
(?<Op1>[^\s]+)          # Continue with capturing valued text into named
(?:\s+)                 # captures and matching, but not capturing space which is ignored.
(?<Op2>[^\s]+)
(?:\s+)
(?<Size>[^\s]+)
(?:\s+)
(?<Month>[^\s]+)
(?:\s+)
(?<Day>[^\s]+)
(?:\s+)
(?<Year>[^\s]+)
(?:\s+)
(?<FileName>[^\r\n]+)";

// Ignore option only applies to the pattern so we can comment it.
var mtGroup = Regex.Match(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Groups;

Console.WriteLine ("In {0} we created {1}", mtGroup["Month"].Value, mtGroup["FileName"].Value);
/* Output

In Apr we created Crystal Reports User Guide.pdf

*/
```