# How to read the creation date from a string[] with FTP ListDirectoryDetails?

Tags: c#, ftp, file-listing

I have a windows service that connects to a FTP server and lists a directory with details. Based on the creation date of the files I am going to download them(I already have the code for the download). I have the function that returns a `string[]` in the following format:

`09-30-14  01:52PM                 9392 test.xlsx`

From what I understood, they could be displayed in a different format like the one posted here: [Parsing FtpWebRequest ListDirectoryDetails line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013486/parsing-ftpwebrequests-listdirectorydetails-line) which is something like that:

`-rw-r--r--    1 ftp      ftp        659450 Jun 15 05:07 TEST.TXT`

The first thing is, how do I deal with different formats?

And the second is, how can I select only files created after a specific time (for example after 09-30-14 01:50PM) ?

Comment: How many different formats do you expect?  If it's just the two, I'd say write your own parser classes for them, which will solve both problems.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing that I don't know what to expect. In my question I missed to say that it's actually a list of FTP servers that my service will connect to. And if we add a new FTP server that uses a different format.. However, I don't really see how this  problem can be solved in the way that I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question, but at first I ended up with making a separate call to the FTP server to get the `LastModified` datetime of the file(not a good solution) and added them to a list of file names with creation dates.
In the end it turned out that the creation date of the file is no longer important for the project, so I just used the standard FTP `ListDirectory`.