# Download the latest file from an FTP server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftp-client

I have to download the latest file from an FTP server. I know how download the latest file from my computer, but I don't how download from an FTP server.

How can I download the latest file from a FTP server?

This is my program to download the latest file from my Computer

```
string startFolder = @"C:\Users\user3\Desktop\Documentos XML";

System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList =
    dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileQuerry =
    from file in fileList
    where file.Extension == ".txt"
    orderby file.CreationTimeUtc
    select file;

foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileQuerry)
{
    var newestFile =
    (from file in fileQuerry
     orderby file.CreationTimeUtc
     select new { file.FullName, file.Name })
     .First();
    textBox2.Text = newestFile.FullName;
}
```

OK, with this code I know the date of the last file, but How I know the name of this file????????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to retrieve timestamps of remote files to select the latest one.

Unfortunately, there's no really reliable and efficient way to retrieve modification timestamps of all files in a directory using features offered by .NET framework, as it does not support the FTP `MLSD` command. The `MLSD` command provides a listing of remote directory in a standardized machine-readable format. The command and the format is standardized by [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7).

Alternatives you can use, that are supported by .NET framework:

- [`ListDirectoryDetails` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails) (the FTP `LIST` command) to retrieve details of all files in a directory and then you deal with FTP server specific format of the details

  DOS/Windows format: [C# class to parse WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails FTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060983/850848#39771146)
  *nix format: [Parsing FtpWebRequest ListDirectoryDetails line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013486/850848#40045894)
- [`GetDateTimestamp` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.getdatetimestamp) (the FTP `MDTM` command) to individually retrieve timestamps for each file. An advantage is that the response is standardized by [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-3) to `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[.sss]`. A disadvantage is that you have to send a separate request for each file, what can be quite inefficient. This method uses the [`LastModified` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebresponse.lastmodified) that you mention:

  ```
  const string uri = "ftp://example.com/remote/path/file.txt";
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", uri, response.LastModified);
  ```

---

Alternatively you can use a 3rd party FTP client implementation that supports the modern `MLSD` command.

For example [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) supports that.

There's even an example for your specific task: [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).
The example is for PowerShell and SFTP, but translates to C# and FTP easily:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Get list of files in the directory
    string remotePath = "/remote/path/";
    RemoteDirectoryInfo directoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

    // Select the most recent file
    RemoteFileInfo latest =
        directoryInfo.Files
            .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)
            .First();

    // Download the selected file
    string localPath = @"C:\local\path";
    session.GetFileToDirectory(latest.FullName, localPath);
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*