# Use "DirectoryInfo" with FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client, directoryinfo, system.io.directory

I would use this instruction:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("ftp://192.168.47.1/DocXML");
```

But I can´t.

How can I use `("ftp://192.168.47.1/DocXML");` with `new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("");`?

This is the code

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.47.1\DocXML");`

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't.

Try this instead:

```
FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.47.1/DocXML");
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("foo", "foo@foo.com");
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
{
...
}
```

Comment: and how I can download the file with the oldest creation date from the FTP server?

Comment: Parse the stream, it should contain the whole files listing. Then, using FtpWebRequest/FtpWebResponse, download the oldest one. Refer to this: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

Comment: but I want to know the oldest file from a FTP server carpet and FtpWebRequest/FtpWebResponse does not help me.

Comment: Sorry, use `req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;` and parse the response to select the oldest one, then download it.

Answer (score 1):

If you a need structured information about files in an FTP directory, you have to use a 3rd party library. The .NET framework does not offer such functionality.

Particularly because it does not support an `MLSD` FTP command, what is the only reliable way to retrieve a machine-readable listing of remote files with their attributes.

---

There are many 3rd party libraries that allow this.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library):

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Get list of files in the directory
    string remotePath = "/remote/path/";
    RemoteDirectoryInfo directoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

    foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} with size {1}, permissions {2} and last modification at {3}",
            fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FilePermissions,
            fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
    }
}
```

References:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30277471/850848#comment48653671_30277592) and your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30280333/850848), you seem to actually need to retrieve the oldest file in FTP directory. For that see:

- [Download the latest file from an FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30259034/850848) (C#)
- [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file) (PowerShell, but translates easily to C#)

Both are for the newest, not oldest, file. Just replace the `.OrderByDescending` with the `.Order` in the C# code to get the oldest file.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

Not working in this way.
I recommend using SFTP instead of FTP. For this I'm using the 3rd party library "SharpSSH".
The following example seems to work:

```
using System.IO;
using Tamir.SharpSsh;
using Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch;

string ip = "DestinationIp";
string user = "JohnDoe";
string password = "YourPassword";
Sftp sftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp(ip, user, password);
sftp.Connect();

FileInfo yourFileInfo = new FileInfo("path");
```

There's also the possibility to add a primary key with
    sftp.AddIdentityFile();