# C# - Download files from FTP which have higher last-modified date

Tags: c#, download, ftp, last-modified

I have an FTP server with some files. I have the same files in in a local directory (in `C:\`).

When I'll run the program, I'd like it searches all files in the FTP server that have a last-modified timestamp later than the same file (equal name) in local directory and download all files founded.

Can someone give me a help or a tip, please? I'll appreciate all answers!

Comment: FTP has a DIR option for getting a list of files.  See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no really reliable and efficient way to retrieve timestamps using features offered by the .NET framework, as it does not support the FTP `MLSD` command. The `MLSD` command provides listing of remote directory in a standardized machine-readable format. The command and the format is standardized by the [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7).

Alternatives you can use that are supported by the .NET framework:

- the [`ListDirectoryDetails` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails) (the FTP `LIST` command) to retrieve details of all files in a directory and then you deal with FTP server specific format of the details (*nix format similar to `ls` *nix command is the most common, drawback is that the format may change over time, as for newer files "May  8 17:48" format is used and for older files "Oct 18  2009" format is used).

  Examples:
  DOS/Windows format: [C# class to parse WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails FTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060983/850848#39771146)
  *nix format: [Parsing FtpWebRequest ListDirectoryDetails line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013486/850848#40045894)
- the [`GetDateTimestamp` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.getdatetimestamp) (an FTP `MDTM` command) to individually retrieve timestamps for each file. An advantage is that the response is standardized by the [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-3) to `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[.sss]`. A disadvantage is that you have to send a separate request for each file, what can be quite inefficient.

  ```
  const string uri = "ftp://example.com/remote/path/file.txt";
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", uri, response.LastModified);
  ```

---

Alternatively you can use a 3rd party FTP client implementation that supports the modern `MLSD` command.

For example the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) supports that.

You can use the [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) or the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) methods and read the [`RemoteFileInfo.LastWriteTime`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo#lastwritetime) of the files in returned collection.

Or even easier, you can use the [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories) to have the library automatically download (synchronize) the modified files:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Synchronize files
    var localPath = @"d:\www";
    var remotePath = "/home/martin/public_html";
    session.SynchronizeDirectories(
        SynchronizationMode.Local, localPath, remotePath, false).Check();
}
```

[WinSCP GUI can generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 2):

List all files : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx

Read date : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.lastmodified(v=vs.110).aspx