# FTP Client FTPwebrequest Directory Listing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, directory-listing

Currently working on a FTP client in vb.net using FTPwebrequest. I have successfully made it work, it's uploading and retrieving all files and displaying it in a Listview. My concern right now is to Sort/Arranged the items in remote directory showed in listview to display the newly added items first and so on.

I have already tried researching online but to no avail. Still looking rightnow.

here is the code for displaying the contents of the directory

```
Private Sub SampleProcedure1()
        Try
            'Create an FTP web request
            Dim ftpwebrequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://" & settings.txtserveraddress.Text & "/" & settings.foldername.Text & "/"), FtpWebRequest)
            'Set properties
            With ftpwebrequest
                'ftp server username and password
                .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(settings.txtserverusername.Text, settings.txtserverpassword.Text)
                'set the method to download
                .Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
                'upload timeout to 100 seconds
                .Timeout = "100000"
            End With

            Dim ftpwebres As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftpwebrequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            Dim ftpstreamreader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ftpwebres.GetResponseStream())
            'clear list of files
            ftpclient.lstfiles.Items.Clear()
            'start loading files from an FTP server into list
            While (ftpstreamreader.Peek() > -1)
                ftpclient.lstfiles.Items.Add(ftpstreamreader.ReadLine())
            End While
            ftpstreamreader.Close()
            ftpwebres.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ftpclient.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            ftpclient.NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Test FTP Client", ex.Message, ToolTipIcon.Info)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

The Listview should display/sort first base on the newest added/uploaded item. right not it sorts backwards and sorts alphabetical.

Comment: Use the `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails`. It contains the informations you need to `.OrderBy()` date `.ThenBy()` name (or it should :).

Comment: Start here: [C# - Download files from FTP which have higher last-modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38073302/850848)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. what i have applied so far the sorting of listbox itself. 'ftpclient.lstfiles.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending'  also im going to try and see if there is similar function like this with ftpwebrequest   'For Each File As String In myDirectory.GetFiles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.LastWriteTime).Select(Function(x) x.CreationTime.Date = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString)
            listAllfiles.Items.Add(File)
        Next'