# FTP server directory listing formats

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am developing an application for downloading file from FTP servers. The FTP servers are updated and different datetime formats, I receive. And I cannot parse them. How can I find the different results format of FTP's? Is there a sit or a general solution for different formats? For example, I received from different servers these formats:

```
1- 08-31-16  10:41PM                   95 Global.asax
2- -rw-r--r--    1 0        0          239832 Apr 01  2014 DriverPackSolution.exe
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard or general solution for formats of the listing response to the FTP `LIST` command. The `LIST` command is what is behind the `ListDirectoryDetails` method of the `FtpWebRequest`.

The `LIST` command was introduced at times, when machine parsing was probably not expected (early 1980's).

To overcome this problem the `MLSD` command was introduced later. Format of a listing for this command is defined by the [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659). An [official example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7.7.3):

```
Type=cdir;Modify=19981107085215;Perm=el; tmp
Type=cdir;Modify=19981107085215;Perm=el; /tmp
Type=pdir;Modify=19990112030508;Perm=el; ..
Type=file;Size=25730;Modify=19940728095854;Perm=; capmux.tar.z
Type=file;Size=1830;Modify=19940916055648;Perm=r; hatch.c
Type=file;Size=25624;Modify=19951003165342;Perm=r; MacIP-02.txt
Type=file;Size=2154;Modify=19950501105033;Perm=r; uar.netbsd.patch
Type=file;Size=54757;Modify=19951105101754;Perm=r; iptnnladev.1.0.sit.hqx
Type=file;Size=226546;Modify=19970515023901;Perm=r; melbcs.tif
Type=file;Size=12927;Modify=19961025135602;Perm=r; tardis.1.6.sit.hqx
Type=file;Size=17867;Modify=19961025135602;Perm=r; timelord.1.4.sit.hqx
Type=file;Size=224907;Modify=19980615100045;Perm=r; uar.1.2.3.sit.hqx
Type=file;Size=1024990;Modify=19980130010322;Perm=r; cap60.pl198.tar.gz
```

Unfortunately the .NET framework does not support the `MLSD` command.

You have to use a 3rd party FTP client library/assembly to take advantage of the standardized `MLSD` command.

See also

- [Parsing FtpWebRequest ListDirectoryDetails line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013486/850848)
- [C# class to parse WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails FTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060983/850848)