# Is there a way to only get files in a date range over FTP?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, sftp, winscp-net

We have a sync process that is daily making sure we have all files from a remote `SFTP` but as time goes on, we're having to download all files just to check that we already file copies in the database by content hash.

Is there a way, let's say using `SSH.NET` or `WinSCP`, to only do this process with files in the last two weeks?

Comment: See [Download files from FTP server in C# to local folder with modification date greater than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44661109/850848).

Comment: It's bit unclear if you want to use SFTP or FTP. In any case, WinSCP supports both.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP)

```
using FluentFTP;
using System.Linq;

.
.
.

DateTime min = ...;
DateTime max = ...;

using (var conn = new FtpClient("address", "user", "password"))
{
    conn.Connect();

    var files = conn
        .GetListing("/path", FtpListOption.Recursive)
        .Where(item => item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File
                    && item.Modified >= min
                    && item.Modified <= max);

    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use `Created` instead of `Modified`

Comment: While OP is indeed bit inconsistent about the use of SFTP and FTP terms, I believe he actually wants to use SFTP, not FTP. So FluentFTP won't help.