# Get file name from FTP Server

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using below Powershell code to query an FTP folder and get the name of the existing file. However, I am not getting the desired output. I get some unwanted results from the code. I appreciate some help in getting the file name only.

Code:

```
$username='Th1sUser'
$password='Th1sPas3'
$ftpuri='ftp://repo.ftpserver.com/Installer'

$uri=[system.URI] $ftpuri
$ftprequest=[system.net.ftpwebrequest]::Create($uri)

$ftprequest.Credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

$ftprequest.Method=[system.net.WebRequestMethods+ftp]::ListDirectory
$response=$ftprequest.GetResponse()
$strm=$response.GetResponseStream()

$reader=New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($strm,'UTF-8')
$list=$reader.ReadToEnd()

Write-Host "$list"
```

Result:

```
Installer/.
Installer/..
Installer/Installerv1.exe
```

I would like to get the installerv1.exe as the file name. Also is there a possibility to get the most recent .exe name from that directory if there are multiple files and get that file name? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the ftp response in order to extract the information you need.

For example, if you need the filename of a line, you can simply loop through the response (line by line) and split the line (which creates an array) and get the last item;

```
ResponselineAsString.split("/")[-1] 

[-1] being the last member of the array

Note: This doesn't tell you if it's a file or a directory
```

If you need the most recent file in a folder, you have at least two ways to achieve this:

While looping through the lines in the response, you can call **[WebRequestMethods.Ftp]::GetDateTimestamp** for each file and then do a comparison in your script.

Or you can call **[WebRequestMethods.Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails** instead of [WebRequestMethods.Ftp]::ListDirectory.

You can find a good example of how to process the response of **ListDirectoryDetails** using regular expressions in the following article:
[Parsing FtpWebRequest ListDirectoryDetails line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013486/parsing-ftpwebrequest-listdirectorydetails-line)

It will provide you with all information you need (dir or file, permissions, date time, etc) and then put the logic you want in your script.